# Android checkSelfPermission for push Notifications

Tags: android, permissions, push-notification

My issue is that I am not sure what String key to use to check for Notification permissions. For key

```
"com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
```

this code always returns true, even if I remove the permission from my Manifest:

```
                int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE");
            if (permissionCheck==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("granted","TRUE");
            }
```

I also tried other permission strings like 'mypkg.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'.

If this is because the Notification permission in the system is considered "normal" and not "dangerous", then how do I detect if the user has disabled Notifications for my app in phone settings (like attached image)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need permissions for notification check.

You can use [NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#areNotificationsEnabled()) method of the support library.
You can use this on API 19+, and for the APIs below this, it always returns `true`.

Comment: NotificationManagerCompat imports fine, but areNotificationsEnabled() says "cannot resolve method".

Comment: You need support library version 24+.

Comment: Ahh it's actually NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled() - thx